# Pascal ABC repeat untill

Tags: pascal

There is a code

```
program roots;
var a, b, c, d,x1, x2,x:real;
begin
  writeln('Введите коэффиценты квадратного уравнения');
  write('a='); readln(a);
  write('b=');readln(b);
  write('c=');readln(c);
  begin
  while a=0 then
  writeln('');
  repeat
  else 
  until
  if a=0
  then
    if b=0
    then
    if c=0
    then writeln('Любое x - решение')
    else writeln('Нет решений')
    else
    begin
      x:=-c/b;
      writeln('x=',x)
      end
     else
      begin
        d:=b*b-4*a*c;
        if d<0
        then writeln('Нет вещенственный корней')
        else
        begin
          x1:=(-b+sqrt(d))/2/a;
          x2:=(-b-sqrt(d))/2/a;
          writeln('x1=',x1);
          writeln('x2=',x2)
          end
      end
end.
```

you need to remake it so that when you enter a = 0, the program writes that the value is incorrect and asks you to enter a again, by repeat

it is desirable to make it faster

Comment: Have you tried any code ?

Answer (score 2):

A `repeat .. until` loop has the following form:

```
repeat

  <code to perform in the loop>

until <condition to terminate the loop>
```

So note that the code you need to repeat is between `repeat` and `until` and the termination condition is after `until`.

In your code you have these lines:

```
  ...
  repeat
  else 
  until
  ...
```

There is no `else` as part of the `repeat .. until`. However, the code block within the loop might of course contain conditional statements with an `else`.